# Combine divs with percentage width with margin in pixels

Tags: html, css

I have a page with multiple items, which have a 33.33% width to fill up the complete width of the page. However, I want to add a 20px margin between the items (both vertically and horizontally, but vertically is the problem here), but just adding a 20px margin on the right of each 1st and 2nd item in a row, destroys the complete page. (remove the commented-out CSS from the fiddle to see what I mean).

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htL6y5Lp/1/)

Now, the question: How do I add a 20px margin and make sure all `.item` divs keep the same size? I could play with the percentage of the width and adding the removed width of an `.item` as a margin, but this would never be a steady 20px, since, well, it's percentages.

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
    <div class="item">10</div>
    <div class="item">11</div>
    <div class="item">12</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main .item {
    height: 100px;
    width:33.33%;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
}
#main .item:nth-child(3n+1) {
    background: red;
}
#main .item:nth-child(3n+3) {
    background: yellow;
}
#main .item:nth-child(3n+2) {
    background:lightblue;
}
/*.item:nth-child(3n+1), .item:nth-child(3n+2) {
    margin-right: 20px !important;
}*/
```

Comment: instead of using `margin` use `padding` instead. Also make sure you're using `box-sizing: border-box` on ALL elements.

Comment: @RobScott Could you explain to me why I should add `box-sizing`? I have never seen that before. Edit: Okay, box-sizing is smart, thanks, very useful for future reference as well. Padding is not an option in my case.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3856h9e2/ Is this your desired result?

Comment: @TusharGupta Yes, that is EXACTLY what I need, thanks! If you add it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Rvervuurt `box-sizing` makes it so when you define `width` it adds into account `margin, padding, and borders`. w/o it, your widths aren't really what you'd expect them to be

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to subtract the `20px` from `33.33%`.

In this case, you would use `width: calc(33.33% - 20px)` to displace the margins.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/cmpyjug8/)

```
#main .item:nth-child(3n+1),
#main .item:nth-child(3n+2) {
    width: calc(33.33% - 20px);
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Unfortunately, this will result in elements of differing widths (since the `20px` isn't being subtracted from all the elements). A better solution would be to subtract `13.33px` from all the elements (`40px`/`3px`):

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/L234z08j/)

```
#main .item {
    height: 100px;
    width: calc(33.33% - 13.33px);
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Problem here is that the 3rd row of `.item`s is a different width than the first and second. I guess it would be possible if I edit the margin so it removes an even (as even as possible) amount of pixels from each row, but that doesn't seem the smartest.

Comment: All these years of doing development and I never knew about this?

Comment: This is great. Solved my problem. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Change the width of each `.item` class and calculate it using the `calc()`

```
#main .item {
    height: 100px;
    width:calc(33.33% - 20px);
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3856h9e2/)**

Comment: How is this different than the answer I posted 10 minutes ago?

Comment: Hmm, the only difference I saw was that they all had the same width, but missed that the third row was also getting a `margin-right`. Your updated answer is better @JoshCrozier

Comment: I think you can find the difference... and moreover OP said that the fiddle was desired so I made it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%` for wrapper and change margin to padding while using `box-sizing: border-box`

```css
.wrapper {
  /* enable to add padding to width */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
}
.item {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">Some thext here</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">Some thext here</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">Some thext here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I should have mentioned I do not have access to the HTML-part.

Comment: not sure if it's a typo or not, but thext -> text ?

Comment: @jbutler483 Yes, typo, but it makes no difference